# ¿Cómo puedo hacer la sumatoria de las variables en PHP?

Tags: php

Soy nuevo programando en `PHP`. Estoy intentando hacer la sumatoria de las variables. Para ello, obtengo datos de la Base de Datos (by select) y los muestro mediante `Google charts` en una gráfica.

Código (obtener datos)

```
function getAlldata(){
// Create connection

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','bems');
    // Check connection

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $dataset = array();
    $data = "";
    $month = (int)strftime("%m")-1;

    if ($month < 10) {
      $month = "0".$month;
    }

    for ($i = 1 ; $i<=getDayInMonth() ; $i++) {

      $dummy = "";
      $dummy2 = ""; 


      if ($i < 10) {
        $runningDate = strftime("%Y")."-".strftime("%m")."-0".$i;
        $dummy = "new Date(".strftime("%Y").",".$month.",0".$i.")";
        $dummy2 = "0".$i."/".strftime("%m")."/".strftime("%Y");
      }else{
        $runningDate = strftime("%Y")."-".strftime("%m")."-".$i;
        $dummy = "new Date(".strftime("%Y").",".$month.",".$i.")";
        $dummy2 = $i."/".strftime("%m")."/".strftime("%Y");
      }


      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `gewertzdaily` WHERE `Date` = '".$runningDate."'";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
      if ($row == null) {
        $dataset[$i] = array("Date"=> $runningDate, "Energy"=> 0 );
      }else{
        $dataset[$i] = array("Date"=> $runningDate, "Energy"=> $row["Energy"] );

      }

      $data = $data."[{v:".$dummy.",f:'".date("D", mktime(0,0,0,strftime("%m"),$i,strftime("%Y")))." ".$dummy2."'},".$dataset[$i]["Energy"]."],";

    }
    $conn->close();
 return $data; 

}
```

Gráfica Google charts:

[image: graph]
![data energy][1]

Siendo las barras de color azul los datos obtenido de la Base de Datos.

¿Como puedo hacer la sumatoria de variables, para que vayan incrementado?

Ejemplo:

- primera columna = data 1
- segunda columna = data 1 + data 2
- tercera columna = data 1 +data 2 + data 3
  ...

¿hay alguna forma de poner las fechas no seleccionadas a 0?

Answer (score 1):

A ver si entiendo bien lo que necesitas sería algo así.

Esta función recibe un número, lo agrega a la variable estática y devuelve el valor incrementado:

```
function sumatoria( $num=NULL ) {
    static $sum = 0;

    if ( $num )
        $sum = $sum + $num;


    return $sum;
}

//Test
echo "Valor inicial: " . sumatoria() . "<br>";      // 0
echo "Nuevo valor: " . sumatoria( 1 ) . "<br>";     // 1
echo "Nuevo valor: " . sumatoria( 5 ) . "<br>";     // 6
echo "Nuevo valor: " . sumatoria( 10 ) . "<br>";    // 16
```

La variable **static** mantiene el último valor asignado, así puede operarse sobre su valor sucesivamente guardando el resultado para las siguientes operaciones. Sin éste modificador, la variable tendría con cada nueva llamada el valor asignado en su declaración.

Comment: Quizás esta respuesta se podría beneficiar con una breve descripción de qué es lo que estás haciendo. Pensemos en alguien que recién comienza. Explicar qué es `static` ampliaría mucho la calidad de la publicación.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una variable acumuladora para ello:

```
/* Ésta será la variable usada para acumular el consumo */
$acumulado = 0;
for ($i = 1 ; $i<=getDayInMonth() ; $i++) {

  $dummy = "";
  $dummy2 = ""; 


  if ($i < 10) {
    $runningDate = strftime("%Y")."-".strftime("%m")."-0".$i;
    $dummy = "new Date(".strftime("%Y").",".$month.",0".$i.")";
    $dummy2 = "0".$i."/".strftime("%m")."/".strftime("%Y");
  }else{
    $runningDate = strftime("%Y")."-".strftime("%m")."-".$i;
    $dummy = "new Date(".strftime("%Y").",".$month.",".$i.")";
    $dummy2 = $i."/".strftime("%m")."/".strftime("%Y");
  }


  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `gewertzdaily` WHERE `Date` = '".$runningDate."'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  if ($row == null) {
    $dataset[$i] = array("Date"=> $runningDate, "Energy"=> 0 );
  }else{
    $dataset[$i] = array("Date"=> $runningDate, "Energy"=> $row["Energy"] );

  }

  /* Aquí actualizo el consumo acumulado hasta la fecha */
  $acumulado += $dataset[$i]["Energy"];
  $data = $data."[{v:".$dummy.",f:'".date("D", mktime(0,0,0,strftime("%m"),$i,strftime("%Y")))." ".$dummy2."'},".$acumulado."],";

}
```

De esa manera envías en la serie el valor acumulado y no el que corresponde a esa serie.

Comment: Aplicando el código de "OscarGarcia", me sale la acumuluacion como la quiero, pero las siguientes fechas obtienen el último valor de lo acumulado, y no el valor "0".

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "las siguientes fechas"? ¿Es que quieres que se resetee en algún momento lo acumulado? ¿Cuándo?

Answer (score 0):

```html
function getAlldata(){
// Create connection

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','bems');
    // Check connection

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $dataset = array();
    $data = "";
    $month = (int)strftime("%m")-1;

    if ($month < 10) {
      $month = "0".$month;
    }

    $SumaTotal = 0;

    for ($i = 1 ; $i<=getDayInMonth() ; $i++) {

      $dummy = "";
      $dummy2 = ""; 


      if ($i < 10) {
        $runningDate = strftime("%Y")."-".strftime("%m")."-0".$i;
        $dummy = "new Date(".strftime("%Y").",".$month.",0".$i.")";
        $dummy2 = "0".$i."/".strftime("%m")."/".strftime("%Y");
      }else{
        $runningDate = strftime("%Y")."-".strftime("%m")."-".$i;
        $dummy = "new Date(".strftime("%Y").",".$month.",".$i.")";
        $dummy2 = $i."/".strftime("%m")."/".strftime("%Y");
      }


      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `gewertzdaily` WHERE `Date` = '".$runningDate."'";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
      if ($row == null) {
        $dataset[$i] = array("Date"=> $runningDate, "Energy"=> 0 );
      }else{
        $dataset[$i] = array("Date"=> $runningDate, "Energy"=> $row["Energy"] );

      }

      $data = "[{v:".$dummy.",f:'".date("D", mktime(0,0,0,strftime("%m"),$i,strftime("%Y")))." ".$dummy2."'},".$dataset[$i]["Energy"]."],";
    $SumaTotal = $SumaTotal + $Data;
    }
    $conn->close();
 return $SumaTotal; 

}
```